# Convert object to Dictionary and get values in WPF

Tags: asp.net, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a `ListView` assigned with `Dictionary<string,Type>` values. While dropping the values the following event will raise. Here i need to get the values of the selected item.

`if (data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Dictionary<string, Type>)))` validation passed. 
But `var info = data.GetData(typeof(Dictionary<string, Type>)) as Dictionary<string, Type>;` returns null.

```
private void Canvas_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = e.Data;
        Point p = e.GetPosition(UIRootCanvas);
        //    MainWindow parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;

        if (data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Dictionary<string, Type>)))
        {
            var info = data.GetData(typeof(Dictionary<string, Type>)) as Dictionary<string, Type>;
            string qq = info.GetType().GetProperties()
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(info)?.ToString() ?? "").Values.ElementAt(0);
            if (qq == "checkbox")

            {
                CheckBox ss = new CheckBox();
                ss.Width = 20;
                UIRootCanvas.Children.Add(ss);
                Canvas.SetLeft(ss, p.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(ss, p.Y);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What `e.Data` is? it is a `Dictonary<string, Type>()`, or what? When I work with drag n drop I usually move an object, usually a usercontrol, with properties and a few other things, and if I need to capture something in it, I usually look for property related to the object I want to capture..